# wrap table column to next row in pdfMake

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I am using PdfMake for my PDF generator in Angular . In that I am using table to display values. I have aroung 14 columns to display. But PdfMake can able to show upto 10 column only, remaing 4 columns are not visible
I want to wrap those 4 columns as next row.

Please help me to acheive this.

Below is my code snippet

```
var dd = {
content: [
    {text: 'Tables', style: 'header'},

    {
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
            body: [
                ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5', 'Column 6', 'Column 7', 'Column 8', 'Column 9', 'Column 10', 'Column 11', 'Column 12', 'Column 13','Column14'],
                ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?','asda','ds','sf','sfs','sf','sf','sfs','sf','sf','sfs','sf']
            ]
        }
    }
```

]
}

Comment: maybe change the pageSize or fontSize  and orientation to landscape?